# Miracles in Pagan Rituals

Tags: tanach, miracle

שלום!

It writes in [ויקרא כה:כג](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> "והארץ לא תמכר לצמתת כי־לי הארץ כי־גרים ותושבים אתם עמדי׃ עמדי׃"
>
> But the land must not be sold beyond reclaim, for the land is Mine; you are but strangers resident with Me.

And in Job it is written in [41:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.41.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) :

> "מִ֣י הִ֭קְדִּימַנִי וַאֲשַׁלֵּ֑ם תַּ֖חַת כׇּל־הַשָּׁמַ֣יִם לִי־הֽוּא׃
>
> Whoever confronts Me I will requite, For everything under the heavens is Mine."

Everything belongs to Gd and nothing is out of his control. So, even miracles that occur according to pagan rituals, happen and with permission by G-d's will?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.55a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en “And lest you lift up your eyes to the heavens, and when you see the sun and the moon and the stars, even all the host of heavens, you are drawn away and worship them, and serve them, which the Lord your God has allotted [ḥalak] to all the nations under the whole heaven” (Deuteronomy 4:19). The verse teaches that God allowed the nations to be misled [sheheḥelikan] by matters that seemingly indicate that idol worship is effective in order to expel the nations from the world due to their decision to engage in idol worship.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. The [Bible](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.13.2?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009_%5Bwith_Onkelos_translation%5D&lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en) says that G-d occasionally gives idol-worshippers miracles as a test for the Jews:

> If a prophet arises among you or a dreamer of a dream, and he gives you an omen or a miracle,
> And the omen or the miracle happens—the one he told you about—saying, ‘‘Let us go after other gods [idols of other nations], that you do not know, and let us serve them.’’
> Do not listen to [accept] the words of that prophet or to that dreamer of a dream, because Adonoy, your God, is testing you to know whether you love Adonoy, your God, wholeheartedly and with your entire beings.